# Valid private keys on curve25519

Tags: elliptic-curves, ed25519

Given that valid private keys on curve25519 must be less than the order of the curve which is (as I understand) already smaller than 2^256, AND a valid key must be clamped to be divisible by 8 and have its high bit set, what is the actual 2^X number of valid private keys approx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The private keys are integers $x$ with $2^{254} \leq x < 2^{255}$ and $x \equiv 0 \pmod 8$, or just $x \in 2^{254} + 8\{0,1,2,\dots,2^{251} - 1\}$, so there are exactly $2^{254}/8 = 2^{251}$ of them.

Comment: Thank you! After factoring in efficient approaches on attacking DLP, curve25519 must have at best <126bit security. Seems low?

Comment: When humanity has spent $2^{100}$ computing cycles in its entire history (which I don't think it has yet), it'll still take millions of times the computing cost spent in the history of humanity to break _one_ X25519 key, so no, that's not really low.  The cost of performing a curve addition is quite a few bit operations, so you can read that to bring the cost in bit operations up to $2^{128}$.